# xfce every window on its monitors panel

Tags: xfce, monitors, multi-monitor, panel

I have triple monitor setup. I run manjaro 15.20 with XFCE4.

I want that if a window, for example chrome, is on the leftmost monitor, it is on the leftmost taskbar/panel. This is how Windows does this. And if firefox is in the middle monitor, it is aswell on the middle taskbar/panel. And the same for the rightmost monitor.

Comment: I would find it confusing to have both the programs on the middle monitor **and** those on the rightmost monitor to show on the middle taskbar/panel, but it is clear that is what you want. What is the question? How to get the stuff from the rightmost and the middle  monitor to show up on the taskbar on the middle monitor?

Comment: @Anthon, I think that the OP wants windows to be listed in the taskbar per monitor. Left on the left, middle on the middle, and right on the right. But it's difficult to be sure.

Comment: I assume you're talking about panel buttons for each window. This setting is available if you double click it or click the gear icon.